# Protect root-owned script against tampering and run unattended w/ sudoers' NOPASSWD

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, sha256

Using `/etc/sudoers` I gave a non-root user (`anyuser` below) permission to sudo-execute a root-owned script (`test-script` below) with the `NOPASSWD:` tag set.
The script's permission octal value is `0550`. Its execution is possible only with one predefined argument (`cache_bak` below) ***and*** when the script file was not tampered with. The latter is possible based on a SHA256 digest-conditioned execution (relevant info in `sudoers` man page).

Things work well , ... until I test-modify the script to get a different SHA digest and see how `sudoers` handles it.

*What I did was:*

```
$ cat /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mkdir -p /var/"$1"
/bin/cp -R /var/cache/* /var/"$1" # copies content of /var/cache/ 
                                  # to /var/$1, defined by script's lone arg 
exit $?
# End of test-script

$ sudo chmod 0550 /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script
$ sudo chown root:admin /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script
$ ls -lsAF test-*   # check
4 -r-xr-x--- 1 root admin   75 Apr 25 18:23 test-script*

$ cat /etc/group | grep sudo   # check
sudo:x:27:anyuser

$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers         # check
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults    insults
root    ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL = (root:ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
%wheel Somehost = (ALL:ALL) ALL
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I then populated `/etc/sudoers.d` with `10_user`, whose content is:

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers.d/10_user
Cmnd_Alias CPVARCACHE = sha256:48805bae82834f323xxxxxxxxxxxxx10145c7bbf80bae183b7de3ea52ef90637 /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script cache_bak

# GROUP SPECS
%admin Somehost = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync

# USER SPECS
anyuser Somehost = (root) NOPASSWD: CPVARCACHE
```

Everything works well, i.e. no passwd is requested and the copy-job gets done, until I simulate having tampered with `test-script`. I did so by adding a line to it, e.g. `if [ "$1" ] ;then :; fi` and running: `sudo /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script cache_bak` again.

The sudo shell does not abort as I expected. Instead it checks that the SHA digest has become different and requests a password for `anyuser` to carry out the job. *However, in that case, I want the line cmd to abort unattended (quietly).*

Attempting to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to /dev/null:

```
# after modifying the script so its SHA digest is different from
#+ that in '/etc/sudoers.d/10_user'

$ sudo /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script cache_bak > /dev/null 2>&1
[sudo] password for anyuser: _^C
```

The above only redirects output of the subshell process, not that of the sudo process.

If the script is tampered with I need the sudo process to abort, presumably even before it launches the script... I saw interesting stuff (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)), but nothing really relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution directly adapted from MarcoS' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869212/redirect-sudo-s-pid-stderr-and-stdout-to-file/36870087#36870087) on StackOverflow is:

```
$ sudo -n /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script cache_bak -- 2> sudo-stderr_"$(date+\%Y\%m\&d-\%H\%M\%S)".log
```

EXPLANATION:
The `-n` flag suppresses' sudo's passwd request. So nothing is displayed on `stdout`. 
If a passwd is nevertheless required, `sudo` dies gracefully after sending an error message to `stdderr`. For example:

```
$ sudo -n ls
sudo: a password is required
```

is immediately followed by `sudo` process death.

To redirect `sudo`'s `stderr`, first add `--` after the sudo'd cmd to signify that `sudo` stops interpreting what comes afterwards as cmd line arguments. Redirection of `stderr` is as usual denoted by `2>` followed by ad-hoc log-filename.

Comment: So...does this deal with the **integrity** check of the script? If so, how? Am I missing something here?  Why would `sudo -n` abort the script if it was somehow modified?

Comment: I guess the answer to the first part of the **Title** is provided in your question already, with the line in `/etc/sudoers`:  `Cmnd_Alias CPVARCACHE = sha256:48805bae82834f323xxxxxxxxxxxxx10145c7bbf80bae183b7de3ea52ef90637 /home/anyuser/Scripts/test-script cache_bak`